# Cannot find symbol on dot?

Tags: java, symbols

I'm always having this error but error and I don't know how to fix it. Ok I will explain you.
  I'm starting to learn code right now and when I write anything with dots(like System.out.printIn()) it gives me this error:cant find symbol. And it points the dot before printIn.
  But its not on all dots, last code i write was:

```
public class Pryt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String aString = "mynameisigna";
        System.out.println(aString);
        String reverse = new StringBuffer(aString).reverse().toString();
        System.out.println(reverse);
        System.out.println(**aString.lenght**);
    }
}
```

And in this case it gives me the error on

```
System.out.println(aString.lenght);
```

The only solution I can take is to copy a example code from internet and I don't find this solution useful.

Comment: What the stars mean in the last `println`? That doesn't look like a valid statement.

Answer (score 4):

1. check your spelling - it's `length`, not `lenght`
2. it's a method, therefore `aString.length()`